# CUDA: How to fill a vector of dynamic size on device and return its contents to another device function?

Tags: c++, cuda

I want to know which is the proper technique to fill an dynamic size array on device (int *row, in the code bellow) and then return  its content, to be used by another device function.

Aiming to contextualize the question, the code bellow attempt to span an arbitrary function in a basis set of Legendre polynomials using Gauss-Legendre quadratures running on the GPU.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__device__  double *d_droot, *d_dweight;

/*How could be returned the array or the pointer to the array int *row, on the device,  that is filled by this function? */
__device__
void Pascal_Triangle(int n_row, int * row) {

  int a[100][100];
  int i, j;

  //first row and first coloumn has the same value=1
  for (i = 1; i <= n_row; i++) {
    a[i][1] = a[1][i] = 1;
  }

  //Generate the full Triangle
  for (i = 2; i <= n_row; i++) {
    for (j = 2; j <= n_row - i; j++) {
      if (a[i - 1][j] == 0 || a[i][j - 1] == 0) {
    break;
      }
      a[i][j] = a[i - 1][j] + a[i][j - 1];
    }
  }

  row = new int[n_row];

  for (i = 1; i <= n_row; i++) {
    row[i] = a[i][n_row-1];
  }

}


__device__
double Legendre_poly(int order, double x)
{
  int n,k;
  double val=0;
  int *binomials;
  for(n=order; n>=0; n--)
    {
      Pascal_Triangle(n, binomials); /*Here are the problems*/
      for(k=0; k<=n; k++)
    val += binomials[k]*pow(x-1,n-k)*pow(x-1,k);
    }

  return val;
}


__device__ __host__
double f(double alpha,double x)
{
  /*function expanded on a basis of Legendre palynomials. */
  return exp(-alpha*x*x);
}


/*Kernel that computes the expansion by quadratures*/
__global__ void Span(int n, double alpha, double a, double b, double *coefficients)
{
  /*
    Parameters:
    n: Total number of expansion coeficients
    a: Upper integration limit
    b: Lower integration limit
    d_droots[]: roots for the quadrature
    d_dweight[]: weights for the quadrature
    coefficients[]: allocate N expansion coefficients.
  */

  double c1 = (b - a) / 2, c2 = (b + a) / 2, sum = 0;
  int dummy;

  int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < n)
    {
      coefficients[i] = 0.0;
      for (dummy = 0; dummy < 5; dummy++)
    coefficients[i] += d_dweight[dummy] * f(alpha,c1 * d_droot[dummy] + c2)*Legendre_poly(dummy,c1 * d_droot[dummy] + c2)*c1;
    }

}


int main(void)
{
  int N = 1<<23;
  int N_nodes = 5;


  double *droot, *dweight, *dresult, *d_dresult, *d_droot_temp, *d_dweight_temp;


  /*double version in host*/
  droot =(double*)malloc(N_nodes*sizeof(double));
  dweight =(double*)malloc(N_nodes*sizeof(double));
  dresult =(double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double)); /*will recibe the results of N quadratures!*/


  /*double version in device*/
  cudaMalloc(&d_droot_temp, N_nodes*sizeof(double));
  cudaMalloc(&d_dweight_temp, N_nodes*sizeof(double));
  cudaMalloc(&d_dresult, N*sizeof(double)); /*results for N quadratures will be contained here*/


  /*double version of the roots and weights*/
  droot[0] = 0.90618;
  droot[1] = 0.538469;
  droot[2] = 0.0;
  droot[3] = -0.538469;
  droot[4] = -0.90618;


  dweight[0] = 0.236927;
  dweight[1] = 0.478629;
  dweight[2] = 0.568889;
  dweight[3] = 0.478629;
  dweight[4] = 0.236927;



  /*double copy host-> device*/
  cudaMemcpy(d_droot_temp, droot, N_nodes*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_dweight_temp, dweight, N_nodes*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_droot, &d_droot_temp, sizeof(double *));
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_dweight, &d_dweight_temp, sizeof(double *));

  // Perform the expansion

  Span<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N,1.0,  -3.0, 3.0, d_dresult); /*This kerlnel works OK*/






  cudaMemcpy(dresult, d_dresult, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);



  cudaFree(d_dresult);
  cudaFree(d_droot_temp);
  cudaFree(d_dweight_temp);

}
```

and here is the makefile to compile the code above:

```
objects = main.o 

all: $(objects)
        nvcc   -arch=sm_20 $(objects) -o span

%.o: %.cpp
        nvcc -x cu -arch=sm_20  -I. -dc $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f *.o span
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(sorry my previous answer was off-base)

You are passing a `row` pointer to this function:

```
void Pascal_Triangle(int n_row, int * row) {
```

You are then attempting to overwrite this pointer with a new value:

```
row = new int[n_row];
```

Once you return from this function, `row` in the calling environment will be unmodified.  (This is an ordinay C/C++ issue, not specific to CUDA.)

This is perhaps a confusing issue, but the *pointer value* of `row` is passed *by value* to the function `Pascal_Triangle`.  You cannot modify the pointer value in the function, and expect the modified value to show up in the calling environment.  (You *can* modify the contents of the locations that the pointer points to, which would be the usual reason to pass `row` by pointer.)

There are a few ways to fix this issue.  The simplest might be just to pass the pointer by reference:

```
void Pascal_Triangle(int n_row, int * &row) {
```

Your code seems to have other defects in it.  I would suggest that you employ [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and also run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.

In particular, the in-kernel `new` operator behaves in a similar fashion to in-kernel `malloc`, and it has [similar limitations](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations).

You are running out of device heap space, so many of your `new` operations are failing, and returning a NULL pointer.

As a test for this, it's good debug practice to put a line like this after your `new` operation:

```
if (row == NULL) assert(0);
```

(you'll also need to include `assert.h`)

If you do that, you'll find that this assert is being hit.

I haven't calculated how much device heap space your code actually needs, but it appears to be using quite a bit.  In C++, it's customary to `delete` an allocation made by `new` once you're done with it.  You might want to investigate freeing the allocations done with `new`, or else (even better) re-use the allocation (i.e. allocate it once per thread), and avoid the reallocation altogether.

here's a modification to your code that demonstrates the above (one allocation per thread) and compiles and runs without error for me:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

__device__  double *d_droot, *d_dweight;

/*How could be returned the array or the pointer to the array int *row, on the device,  that is filled by this function? */
__device__
void Pascal_Triangle(int n_row, int *row) {

  int a[100][100];
  int i, j;

  //first row and first coloumn has the same value=1
  for (i = 1; i <= n_row; i++) {
    a[i][1] = a[1][i] = 1;
  }

  //Generate the full Triangle
  for (i = 2; i <= n_row; i++) {
    for (j = 2; j <= n_row - i; j++) {
      if (a[i - 1][j] == 0 || a[i][j - 1] == 0) {
    break;
      }
      a[i][j] = a[i - 1][j] + a[i][j - 1];
    }
  }

  for (i = 1; i <= n_row; i++) {
    row[i] = a[i][n_row-1];
  }

}


__device__
double Legendre_poly(int order, double x, int *my_storage)
{
  int n,k;
  double val=0;
  int *binomials = my_storage;
  if (binomials == NULL) assert(0);
  for(n=order; n>=0; n--)
    {
      Pascal_Triangle(n, binomials); /*Here are the problems*/
      for(k=0; k<=n; k++)
    val += binomials[k]*pow(x-1,n-k)*pow(x-1,k);
    }
  return val;
}


__device__ __host__
double f(double alpha,double x)
{
  /*function expanded on a basis of Legendre palynomials. */
  return exp(-alpha*x*x);
}


/*Kernel that computes the expansion by quadratures*/
__global__ void Span(int n, double alpha, double a, double b, double *coefficients)
{
  /*
    Parameters:
    n: Total number of expansion coeficients
    a: Upper integration limit
    b: Lower integration limit
    d_droots[]: roots for the quadrature
    d_dweight[]: weights for the quadrature
    coefficients[]: allocate N expansion coefficients.
  */

  double c1 = (b - a) / 2, c2 = (b + a) / 2, sum = 0;
  int dummy;

  int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < n)
    {
      #define MY_LIM 5
      int *thr_storage = new int[MY_LIM];
      if (thr_storage == NULL) assert(0);
      coefficients[i] = 0.0;
      for (dummy = 0; dummy < MY_LIM; dummy++)
        coefficients[i] += d_dweight[dummy] * f(alpha,c1 * d_droot[dummy] + c2)*Legendre_poly(dummy,c1 * d_droot[dummy] + c2, thr_storage)*c1;
      delete thr_storage;
    }

}


int main(void)
{
  cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, (1048576ULL*1024));
  int N = 1<<23;
  int N_nodes = 5;


  double *droot, *dweight, *dresult, *d_dresult, *d_droot_temp, *d_dweight_temp;


  /*double version in host*/
  droot =(double*)malloc(N_nodes*sizeof(double));
  dweight =(double*)malloc(N_nodes*sizeof(double));
  dresult =(double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double)); /*will recibe the results of N quadratures!*/


  /*double version in device*/
  cudaMalloc(&d_droot_temp, N_nodes*sizeof(double));
  cudaMalloc(&d_dweight_temp, N_nodes*sizeof(double));
  cudaMalloc(&d_dresult, N*sizeof(double)); /*results for N quadratures will be contained here*/


  /*double version of the roots and weights*/
  droot[0] = 0.90618;
  droot[1] = 0.538469;
  droot[2] = 0.0;
  droot[3] = -0.538469;
  droot[4] = -0.90618;


  dweight[0] = 0.236927;
  dweight[1] = 0.478629;
  dweight[2] = 0.568889;
  dweight[3] = 0.478629;
  dweight[4] = 0.236927;



  /*double copy host-> device*/
  cudaMemcpy(d_droot_temp, droot, N_nodes*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_dweight_temp, dweight, N_nodes*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_droot, &d_droot_temp, sizeof(double *));
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_dweight, &d_dweight_temp, sizeof(double *));

  // Perform the expansion

  Span<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N,1.0,  -3.0, 3.0, d_dresult); /*This kerlnel works OK*/






  cudaMemcpy(dresult, d_dresult, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);



  cudaFree(d_dresult);
  cudaFree(d_droot_temp);
  cudaFree(d_dweight_temp);

}
```

This code has a couple advantages:

1. it can run with a much smaller reservation on the device heap
2. it's considerably quicker than the vast number of allocations that your code was trying to do.

**EDIT:**

instead of the `assert` you could do something like this:

```
/*Kernel that computes the expansion by quadratures*/
__global__ void Span(int n, double alpha, double a, double b, double *coefficients)
{
  /*
    Parameters:
    n: Total number of expansion coeficients
    a: Upper integration limit
    b: Lower integration limit
    d_droots[]: roots for the quadrature
    d_dweight[]: weights for the quadrature
    coefficients[]: allocate N expansion coefficients.
  */

  double c1 = (b - a) / 2, c2 = (b + a) / 2, sum = 0;
  int dummy;

  int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < n)
    {
      #define MY_LIM 5
      int *thr_storage = new int[MY_LIM];
      if (thr_storage == NULL) printf("allocation failure!\");
      else {
        coefficients[i] = 0.0;
        for (dummy = 0; dummy < MY_LIM; dummy++)
          coefficients[i] += d_dweight[dummy] * f(alpha,c1 * d_droot[dummy] + c2)*Legendre_poly(dummy,c1 * d_droot[dummy] + c2, thr_storage)*c1;
        delete thr_storage;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems my device does not supports assert because the execution with cuda-memcheck report some errors, any sugestions?

Comment: [assert](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#assertion) requires a cc2.0 or higher GPU and it will not work on MacOS.  Instead of the assertion, you can use a `printf` statement and an `if` statement to condition the rest of the code.  Since this is in your kernel code, it should be easy to do.  I edited my answer with a possible example.