# Copying array of structs from host to device cuda

Tags: c, cuda

Suppose I have a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct values{
int one, int two, int three
} values;
```

Now, suppose I create an array of values on the host and populate with random data

```
values vals*;
__device__ values* d_vals;
int main(){
     vals = (values*)malloc(sizeof(values) * A_LARGE_NUMBER);
     PopulateWithDate(); //populates vals with random data
}
```

Now I want to be able to copy the values to the device such that I can access them in my kernel like so:

```
__global__ void myKernel(){
     printf("%d", d_vals[0].one);//I don't really want to print, but whenever I try to access I get an error
}
```

Whatever I try I get an illegal memory access was encountered error.

Here's my current attempt:

```
int main(){
     vals = (values*)malloc(sizeof(values) * A_LARGE_NUMBER);
     PopulateWithDate(); //populates vals with random data

     values* d_ptr;
     cudaGetSymbolAddress((void**)&d_ptr, d_vals);
     cudaMalloc((void**)&d_ptr, A_LARGE_NUMBER * sizeof(values));

     cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_ptr, &vals, sizeof(values) * A_LARGE_NUMBER);
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();
     dim3    blocksPerGrid(2, 2);
     dim3    threadsPerBlock(16, 16);

    myKernel<< <blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >> >();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you have shown so far, using a `__device__` pointer variable just creates needless complexity.  Just use an ordinary dynamic allocation using `cudaMalloc` for device storage, and otherwise follow an approach similar to any of the CUDA sample codes such as vectorAdd.  Here is an example:

```
$ cat t1315.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#define A_LARGE_NUMBER 10

struct values{
int one, two, three;
};

values *vals;

__global__ void myKernel(values *d_vals){
     printf("%d\n", d_vals[0].one);
}

void PopulateWithData(){
  for (int i = 0; i < A_LARGE_NUMBER; i++){
    vals[i].one = 1;
    vals[i].two = 2;
    vals[i].three = 3;
  }
}


int main(){
     vals = (values*)malloc(sizeof(values) * A_LARGE_NUMBER);
     PopulateWithData(); //populates vals with random data

     values* d_ptr;
     cudaMalloc((void**)&d_ptr, A_LARGE_NUMBER * sizeof(values));
     cudaMemcpy(d_ptr, vals, A_LARGE_NUMBER *sizeof(values),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     dim3    blocksPerGrid(1,1);
     dim3    threadsPerBlock(1, 1);

    myKernel<< <blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >> >(d_ptr);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1315 t1315.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1315
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

You had a variety of other basic (non-CUDA) coding errors in what you had shown, I'm not going to try and run through them all.

If you really want to retain your `__device__` pointer variable, and use that to point to the device data (array of structs) then you will still need to use `cudaMalloc`, and the overall process takes additional steps.  You can follow the example worked out in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860120/cuda-how-to-fill-a-vector-of-dynamic-size-on-device-and-return-its-contents-to/28861259#28861259).

Following that example, here's a set of changes to the above code to make it work with a `__device__` pointer variable instead of a pointer passed as a kernel parameter:

```
$ cat t1315.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#define A_LARGE_NUMBER 10

struct values{
int one, two, three;
};

values *vals;
__device__ values *d_vals;

__global__ void myKernel(){
     printf("%d\n", d_vals[0].one);
}

void PopulateWithData(){
  for (int i = 0; i < A_LARGE_NUMBER; i++){
    vals[i].one = 1;
    vals[i].two = 2;
    vals[i].three = 3;
  }
}


int main(){
     vals = (values*)malloc(sizeof(values) * A_LARGE_NUMBER);
     PopulateWithData(); //populates vals with random data

     values* d_ptr;
     cudaMalloc((void**)&d_ptr, A_LARGE_NUMBER * sizeof(values));
     cudaMemcpy(d_ptr, vals, A_LARGE_NUMBER *sizeof(values),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_vals, &d_ptr, sizeof(values*));
     dim3    blocksPerGrid(1,1);
     dim3    threadsPerBlock(1, 1);

    myKernel<< <blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >> >();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1315 t1315.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1315
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the helpful response. I'm sorry I wasn't too clear in my question. The thing is I have to use a device pointer because myKernel is not going to be called from main. Instead, it will be called after I recieve a random event from some external code. In other words, I will not be able to pass d_ptr as a parameter to the kernel, I have to keep a reference to it somewhere

Comment: OK the changes are relatively minor, so I added an example demonstrating the changes.